# Haskell linear algebra?

Tags: haskell, matrix, linear-algebra, gsl

I am starting to test Haskell for linear algebra.  Does anyone have any recommendations for the best package for this purpose?  Any other good resources for doing basic matrix manipulation with Haskell?

The haskell wiki [lists several resources for this](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Libraries_and_tools/Mathematics#Linear_algebra).  My current focus in on [hmatrix](https://github.com/albertoruiz/hmatrix) and [bindings-gsl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bindings-gsl), both of which look promising.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The hmatrix and hmatrix-static libraries are excellent. Hunt around on Hackage some more: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vect

Comment: Don, it looks like you suggest hmatrix and point to a different package (vect)?

Answer (score 1):

We have now more complete support for LAPACK's matrix types like triangular, symmetric, Hermitian, banded matrices and according functions in single and double precision in https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lapack