# Presenting Matrix in Haskell

Tags: haskell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Haskell linear algebra?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343313/haskell-linear-algebra)

I am wondering whether is there any standard library to present a matrix and all its operators in Haskell? I am quite new to Haskell, so if you have experience handling with matrix, please give me some example if you can.

Comment: Have you tried [google](https://encrypted.google.com/search?hl=en&q=matrix%20haskell) and [Hayoo](http://holumbus.fh-wedel.de/hayoo/hayoo.html?query=matrix)? If so, could you indicate this so that we know you've done due diligence. (Also, the first result on google is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343313/haskell-linear-algebra), which leads to [this](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Libraries_and_tools/Mathematics#Linear_algebra).)

Comment: What do you want to do with it? I'd think you probably wouldn't use the same library for occasionally multiplying 10kx10k matrices expecting to get a result as accurate as possible vs. having to multiply 100k 4x4 matrices 100 times per second, and it's ok if it's a little inaccurate.

Answer (score 4):

I don't have firsthand experience with it, but [hmatrix](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hmatrix) is a go-to package for matrices in Haskell.

As for examples, there are dozens of good ones in the package file, in the "examples" directory. You can get the package file by running `cabal unpack hmatrix`, or just download it [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hmatrix/0.14.1.0/hmatrix-0.14.1.0.tar.gz).

Comment: `cabal install hmatrix` to install the package, `cabal unpack hmatrix` to unzip the package file locally.

Comment: @dave4420: Nice! I actually didn't know that. Updating my answer.